# How to downgrade base with cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to install a program called [clanki](https://github.com/marcusbuffett/Clanki) on Windows 10. In it's installation doc it says to use 'cabal install clanki'. I downloaded cabal, then ghc. Now I run into a version problem for the package `base`.

```
$ cabal install clanki
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: clanki-1.2.7 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of clanki-1.2.7)
rejecting: base-4.9.0.0/installed-4.9... (conflict: clanki => base<=4.9.0)
rejecting: base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0,
base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0,
base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0,
base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0,
base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable
package requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

So clanki requires base to be older than 4.9 (stack says this more clearly than cabal), and I then would like to downgrade base to 4.8.2.0. When I try `ghc-pkg unregister base`, it doesn't allow me. Not even with `--force`:

```
$ ghc-pkg unregister base --force
unregistering would break the following packages: xhtml-3000.2.1 Win32-2.3.1.1 transformers-0.5.2.0 time-1.6.0.1 template-haskell-2.11.0.0 process-1.4.2.0 pretty-1.1.3.3 hpc-0.6.0.3 hoopl-3.10.2.1 haskeline-0.7.2.3 ghci-8.0.1 ghc-boot-th-8.0.1 ghc-boot-8.0.1 ghc-8.0.1 filepath-1.4.1.0 directory-1.2.6.2 deepseq-1.4.2.0 containers-0.5.7.1 Cabal-1.24.0.0 bytestring-0.10.8.1 binary-0.8.3.0 array-0.5.1.1 (ignoring)
```

As I mentioned, I tried also with stack, but in the end it also comes down to the wrong version of base. How can I downgrade this package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. `base` is fixed to the GHC install; the only way to get a different version is to install an older compiler, i.e. GHC-7.10. [`stack`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) would automatically do that for you, but I wouldn't be sure if that's the best solution.

Likely enough, the package *will* actually work with GHC-8.0; in fact the constraint `base <= 4.9.0` indicates that it should. That constraint doesn't make a lot of sense since it only allows the pre-first subrevision; it should probably really be `base < 4.10`.

So the best thing would be to download the source from github, where `base` does in fact not have the upper bound, and install it from the local folder with `cabal install`. If that works, notify the author to relax the bound on Hackage.

If it doesn't compile in GHC-8.0, again the best thing would be to *make it work* by editing the source and then file a pull request.

Alternatively, I'd then resort to stack for installing the package with an older GHC. To do this, get the source code *with the `base < 4.9` constraint* (you need to insert that in the github code), and run `stack setup`, `stack init` and `stack install`.

Comment: How about overriding the constraint with `cabal install clanki --allow-newer base`

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: I didn't actually know that option, but that's great! Why don't you make it an answer?

Answer (score 13):

According to @leftroundabout’s answer, the upper bound on `base` in this package is bogus. In such a case, or simply if you feel bold, you can instruct `cabal` to ignore upper bounds on dependencies with the appropriate option:

```
cabal install clanki --allow-newer=base
```