# couldn't install leksah on Ubuntu 16.10 using cabal 1.24.0.2/ghc 8.2.1

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, leksah

I'm trying to install leksah as my development environment using cabal but I ran into errors.

```
user@home:~$ cabal install leksah
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: leksah-0.15.2.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of leksah-0.15.2.0)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0/installed-4.1... (conflict: leksah => base>=4.0.0.0 && <4.9)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0,
base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0,
base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0,
base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1,
base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1
(constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
Backjump limit reached (currently 2000, change with --max-backjumps or 
try to run with --reorder-goals).
```

other detauls regarding haskell install in my machine are as follows -

```
user@home:~$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.1
user@home:~$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library 
user@home:~$ stack --version
Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 (4395 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.15.0
```

Any suggestions to resolve these errors?

Comment: I don't think you are following the right instructions: https://github.com/leksah/leksah#building-from-source

Comment: sibi- I followed the steps and got the same error

Comment: Can you try the stack variant of the installation process ?

Comment: @Sibi - stack variant works !!! But I think its worth try to look into what is the issue using cabal.

Comment: Newcomers: don't use Leksah, it's buggy and dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get the dependencies straight:

- `leksah` has version `0.15.2`, which has been released ~18 months ago. It depends on a `base` package strictly lower than `4.9` (see also the [version bump commit](https://github.com/leksah/leksah/blob/67c2f4b5e9bd831b328c69c84b14a0af33d325da/leksah.cabal)).
- `ghc` has version `8.2.1`. According to the [release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/8.2.1-notes.html), the `base` package has version `4.10.0.0`.

You cannot install another base package - it is intrinsically linked to the ghc version ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022261/how-to-downgrade-base-with-cabal)). Note that the version of the base package for `ghc 8.0.1` ([release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/8.0.1-notes.html#base)) is`4.9.0.0`.

---

So either

- install a haskell version prior to 8, bringing with it an older base package, or
- install `leksah` from its github source ([install instructions](https://github.com/leksah/leksah#building-from-source)), or
- work with the other contributors to perhaps release a `0.15.1` (or whatever) just bumping versions (provided it's still working of course).

It looks weird though - there are commits in the last two weeks, however the [download](https://github.com/leksah/leksah/wiki/download) page mentions that they are planning a `0.16` version - this was half a year ago.

---

I'm kind of wondering why there is an upper limit on `ghc`s minor version - currently the [version requirement](https://github.com/leksah/leksah/blob/master/leksah.cabal) is set to base `>=4.0.0.0 && <4.11`. So when a `ghc next` bumps the `base` package again, the same problem arises. So `leksah` is pretty much locked to the `ghc` release cycle.